# Error in AudioFileWritePackets

Tags: objective-c, wav, audiounit

i'm just trying to capture the mic and save data to wav file ! and here is the code:

```
AudioFileID FileID=remoteIOplayer->mixAudioFile;
if (inBusNumber == 16){
    AudioUnitRender(audioUnit, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, 1, inNumberFrames, ioData);
    OSStatus result = AudioFileWritePackets(FileID, false, (inNumberFrames * 4), NULL, mixpacketNum, &inNumberFrames, ioData->mBuffers[i].mData);
    if (result != noErr){
        NSLog(@"Error Writing");
        mixpacketNum += inNumberFrames;
}
}
```

and i created the file correctly with the following format that also used to capture the mic:

```
audioFormat.mSampleRate         = 44100.00;
    audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 2;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 2;
```

the error is result OSStatus    -38 fnopnerr (file not open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your call to open the audio file either failed or wasn't done before rendering started. What does your call to `AudioFileCreateWithURL` look like?